# Angularjs service mixing $resource and $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-service

I'm currently working on a service that can determine where should the controller get the data from (external url or internal server).

Here the part of my example code

```
//Controller
$q.all([
    CommonAPI.GetListing().$promise,
    ...
    ...
]).then(function(res){
    $scope.listing = res[0];
});

//CommonAPI service
function GetListing() {
    var externalURL = config.listingURL || '';

    if(externalURL) {
        return $http.get(externalURL);
    } else {
        return InternalAPI.GetListing(); //$resource service
    }
}

//InternalAPI service
.factory(...
    return $resource('Internal', {} , {
        GetListing: {
            method: 'GET',
            url: 'internal/listing'
        }
    }); ...
```

Here the problem, if there is no `externalURL` the function works fine with the `$resource` method, but if there is `externalURL` and using the `$http` method, the response get `undefined`.

If I change the promise inside the `$q` to `CommonAPI.GetListing()` without `.$promise`, it works fine with the `$http` method, but not `$resource`.

Is there any way to solve this issue ? I guess i can split it to 2 different service, 1 for `$http` and 1 for `$resource` and do a condition check before the `$q`, but I prefer not to.

Any help to this will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried returning a promise instead of `$http.get()` ?

Like:

```
if(externalURL) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      $http.get(externalURL)
           .then(response => resolve(response))
           .catch(error => reject(error));
    }
}
```

Another approach you could try is to not use `$q.all` and instead split your logic into 2 methods.
First check if `externalURL` exists and then call either method to handle the data:

```
if (externalURL) {
     // callHTTPMethod
} else {
    // call resource method
}
```

Note that this way you have more control over `$q.all` but you need to handle each response separately in their respective methods.

Comment: I have tried the `new Promise` method, it seems give me the same result, and the second option is what I trying to avoid of, would put it as last option if unable to find any solution for this, thx anyway.